# What causes macOS to stop launching all apps?

Tags: macos, bug

I don't get error messages and the apps I have open still work fine, but my Mac is refusing to launch any new apps, including terminal.app.

- It doesn't matter if I try to launch an app through spotlight search, the bottom bar, Finder, or if I use Show Package Contents -> macos -> click on UNIX file.
- I tried to get around this by opening About this Mac and clicking
  Displays Preferences to open System Preferences, but now About this
  Mac is stuck permanently open with the spinning mouse wheel whenever
  I mouse over it.

My system is M1 Macbook Air 11.2.1.  Normal restarting doesn't
help, since the OS reopens the programs I have as start-up
applications.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to safe mode and see about getting a backup going.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

If that doesn’t help, next boot to recovery OS and run disk utility to repair the boot volume.

Past that, you’ll need a little more information for next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted a second time and everything was fixed!